# linux usb libusb parsing non standard descriptors

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

I'm using libusb for user-mode USB handling in an application. For now, it works quite nicely with some of the simpler USB devices I can find (like mass storage devices), but for more complicated devices like HID devices or AV class devices, I need to be able to parse HID descriptors and interface association descriptors.

libusb only parses/exposes standard USB descriptors (configuration, interface, etc). Can anyone recommend a library to parse the other non-standard descriptors, like IA and HID descriptors, out of the configuration descriptor blob?

Comment: Does HID descriptor included in configuration descriptor suite your needs? http://pastebin.com/vHfa5utN

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a simple little library that has all of the struct and type definitions for the non-standard descriptors, and also parses them out of the config descriptor and perhaps does some validation/sanity checking. If it also had a more abstract interface that would provide condensed information on HID properties, etc, that would be nice too.